# Find specific key/value in array of objects and print out another key/value in that object

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, world-of-warcraft, battlenet-api

I have this response from a $.getJSON call. Now I want to select the name property of the object with "selected": true, and print it to a div with id charTitle.

```
"titles": [{
        "id": 17,
        "name": "Sergeant %s"
    }, {
        "id": 53,
        "name": "%s, Champion of the Naaru"
    }, {
        "id": 64,
        "name": "%s, Hand of A'dal",
        "selected": true
    }]
```

Comment: try using underscore.js http://underscorejs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a simple loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.titles.length; i++) {
    if (obj.titles[i].selected) {
        $('#charTitle').text(obj.titles[i].name);
    }
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/khdxwfdz/)

Or with jQuery's `$.each()`:

```
$.each(obj.titles, function(i, title) {
    if (title.selected)
        $('#charTitle').text(title.name);        
});
```

Note that if you have multiple objects in the array with `selected` set to `true` you would need to use `append()` instead of `text()` to set the content of the `div`, otherwise the previous value will be overwritten.

Comment: Thank you so much! I never realized I could loop through it all and just look for the selected/true and then run code.
Starting to see the power of loops now! :)

Answer (score 0):

using underscore you can get this with

```
var titles = ...
_.findWhere(titles, {selected: true});
```

see http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Array.prototype.filter()`

```js
var arr = [{
  "id": 17,
  "name": "Sergeant %s"
}, {
  "id": 53,
  "name": "%s, Champion of the Naaru"
}, {
  "id": 64,
  "name": "%s, Hand of A'dal",
  "selected": true
}]

var res = arr.filter(function(val, key) {
  return val.selected === true
})[0].name;

$("#charTitle").html(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="charTitle"></div>
```